# Link to facebook from my website is considered potential phishing

Tags: facebook, security, phishing

I own a website featuring a web page ( http://digilander.libero.it/karmaproductions/MakHOME.htm ) that is intended to be used as a "browser home page", which includes a link to Facebook. 
Since a few days/weeks (I don't know for sure), when clicking on this link, a warning is received by Facebook ( https://www.facebook.com/w.php?h=AeQ_7Doivu7wB392 ):

> Warning
>
> The website directing you here was not a Facebook page. If you entered
>   your Facebook login information on the previous site, you will need to
>   change your password. To learn more about staying safe on the
>   internet, visit our Security Page. You can also check out the phishing
>   Wikipedia article.

My website is no phishing or scam, how can I prevent my users from receiving this scary message?
Is there a way to put my website in a "whitelist" of trusted referrers? Internet Archive proves my above cited web page is trustworthy since many years now.

Comment: Hmm, that's actually scary...perhaps they are parsing for `input` elements?

Comment: It is indeed just the referer that causes Facebook to display this message and not something weird about that link that you haven't told us about - referer spoofing with e.g. [Referer Control](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/referer-control/hnkcfpcejkafcihlgbojoidoihckciin) is sufficient to cause the message to appear. Any referer from http://digilander.libero.it/ causes the message to appear when navigating directly to http://www.facebook.com. Referers from other arbitrarily chosen domains do not trigger the message. You appear to have been blacklisted for some reason.

Comment: If a blacklist does even exist, some other website from the same provider (libero.it) might have been blacklisted, I believe not my website (i.e., "karmaproductions"). So, anything I can do?

Comment: Please, if you know how I can fix this, or if you know where I can ask...

Comment: Ehm... can I bump? I still hope for one possible answer.

Comment: Since I got nowhere else to ask, please help me find some way to contact Facebook staff, I would really appreciate any suggestion. I still have this issue.